# Prop getting lost in unusual situation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying to pass props from my parent component to my child component. When I receive the props in componentWillReceiveProps(), one of the children of my coin prop gets lost. This can be seen with the console.log lines in the child component.

For some reason, coin.profit prints "undefined" while printing just the coin object shows that coin.profit indeed is in the coin object. I have looked over my code for hours now, and asked friends to look at it and to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Child Component (https://github.com/kdelalic/cryptofolio/blob/master/src/js/progress.js):

```
class Progress extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        initial: 0,
        profit: 0,
        holdings: 0,
        change: "0%"
    };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.coins !== this.props.coins) {
        Object.keys(nextProps.coins).map((key) => {
            const coin = nextProps.coins[key]
            console.log(coin)
            console.log(coin.price)
            console.log(coin.profit)
            this.setState({
                initial: this.state.initial + coin.price * coin.amount,
                profit: this.state.profit,
                holdings: this.state.profit + this.state.holdings,
                change: this.state.initial / this.state.profit * 100 + "%",
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Parent Component (https://github.com/kdelalic/cryptofolio/blob/master/src/js/crypto.js):

```
class Crypto extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        open: false,
    };
}

getCurrentPrice = (key) => {
    const { coins } = this.state;
    var url = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=" + coins[key].value.substring(coins[key].value.indexOf("(")+1,coins[key].value.indexOf(")")).toUpperCase() + "&tsyms=" + coins[key].currency.toUpperCase();
    axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            const price = response.data[coins[key].currency.toUpperCase()];
            const profit = parseFloat((price - coins[key].price) * coins[key].amount).toFixed(2)

            var newState = this.state;
            newState.coins[key]["currentPrice"] = price;
            newState.coins[key]["profit"] = profit;
            this.setState(newState);
        })
        .catch(err => {               
            console.log(err)
        });     
};

checkPos = (num) => {
    if (num > 0) {
        return " positive"
    } else if (num < 0) {
        return " negative"
    } else {
        return ""
    }
};

handleOpen = () => {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, open: true });
};

handleClose = () => {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, open: false });
};

coinData = (dataFromChild, key) => {
    const newCoins = {
        ...this.state.coins
    };
    newCoins[key] = dataFromChild
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        coins: newCoins
    }, () => {
        this.getCurrentPrice(key);
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
        })
        this.handleClose();
    })
};

render() {
    const { coins } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="crypto">
            <Progress coins={this.state.coins}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, you should never mutate the existing state. In

```
var newState = this.state;
newState.coins[key]["currentPrice"] = price;
newState.coins[key]["profit"] = profit;
this.setState(newState);
```

you are never creating any new objects. You should be doing

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  coins: {
    ...this.state.coins,
    [key]: {
      ...this.state.coins[key],
      currentPrice: price,
      profit,
    },
  },
});
```

to create new state objects for each item you are mutating.

Because you are modifying the existing object, means the object passed to `componentWillReceiveProps` will potentially be updated by your other code.

Comment: He can also use `_.cloneDeep()`, that should make somewhat easier.